# Determine the distance between the point $(2,-3,1)$ and the point of intersection of three planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Determine the distance between the point $(2,-3,1)$ and the point of intersection of the following system.

$3x-y+z=4$

$-x+2y+3z=7$

$x+3y+4z=12$

I'm not quite sure how to do this?

Comment: These are two problems molded together in one. First you need to calculate the point of intersection of those three planes. Many ways to do that. Is the graphing calculator allowed? Then it can be done with RREF. Manually? Use Gauss elimination for example. Once you have that point of intersection, you need to apply the Distance formula, which ,  I am sure you have seen before.

Comment: @Aweygan its 12 sorry

Comment: I havent, Im teaching myself calculus can u please explain step by step if u can @imranfat

Answer (score 2):

The hardest part is finding the point of intersection between the three planes.  To do that, you can rewrite it as a matrix equation then apply Gaussian elimination, or you can just do it by hand.

Adding the $2$nd and $3$rd equations yields
$$ 5y+7z=19. \tag{1}$$
Adding the $1$st equation and $3$ times the $2$nd equation gives
$$ 5y+10z=25. \tag{2}$$
Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ gives
$$ 3z=6\iff z=2. $$
Substituting this into $(1)$ gives
$$ 5y+7(2)=19\iff y=1. $$
Now, plugging in $y=1$ and $z=2$ into the first equation gives us
$$ 3x-1+2=4 \iff x=1. $$
Thus, the point of intersection of the three planes is $(x,y,z)=(1,1,2).$ Now just find the distance between this point and $(2,-3,1)$.

Comment: @raj. Love the bread and butter math...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) followed by the [Euclidean Distance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)  If you don't know how to use either of these, read up on them from the links provided and from other sources(I recommend Lang's Linear Algebra as a introduction to the subject, but that is slightly off topic). The row echelon form of our system is:

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{4}{3} \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &2\end{array}\right)$

Solving this, we get $x = 1, y = 1, z = 2$. So we want the distance between $(1, 1, 2)$ and $(2, -3, 1)$ which by the distance formula is $$\sqrt{(1-2)^2 + (1+3)^2 + (2-1)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 16 + 1} = 3\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: That matrix is not in *reduced* row echelon form

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed(hopefully).

Comment: Looks right to me! +1 for referring people to Lang.  That's what I learned linear algebra from.